# When is the net/http Serve method expected to return an error?

Tags: go

Given the following function:

```
func main() {
    l := createListener(8080)
    r := ksws.CreateRouter()

    if err := http.Serve(l, r); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("An error occured.")
    }
}
```

I'm wondering why I should catch the 'error' returned from the 'http.Serve' method?
It seems that an error is never returned here.

However, according to the documentation https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Serve the Serve method always returns a non-nill error.

Can someone provide me some guidance on this?

Comment: there is no error-less way to stop such server (it will be "context cancelled", or abrupt termination for some other reasons). At startup it might encounter fatal errors if the port is already being listened, or if you try to bind a restricted port without proper permissions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple case: when port `8080` already used you'll have error:

```
listen tcp :8080: bind: address already in use
```

Another case: `http.Serve` calls `srv.trackListener` which also may fail in case `go` didn't manage to add listener.

Also: `http.Serve` calls `l.Accept()` which also may fail...

So there are many possible cases...

And also it's idiomatic for `go` to check all errors returned by any function.

PS: It's way better to have redundant error check than to have silent not working program (imho)...

Comment: This error will happen on the `net.Listen` method and not on the `Serve` method. I'm searching for the answer when the `Serve` method will throw.

Comment: @Complexity I've added couple more examples.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the source code and it might shine some light into your question.

https://golang.org/src/net/http/server.go?s=75585:75634#L2838

`// Serve always returns a non-nil error and closes l.
// After Shutdown or Close, the returned error is ErrServerClosed.`

So the error will alway be return either with a `real error` if something went wrong or the `ErrServerClosed` in case of a shutdown or close, which happen for several reasons.

Answer (score 0):

in your code when you ctrl-c, note that the prints does not occur because the program has ended. you should listen to signals to prevent that behavior.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    c := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(c, os.Interrupt)

    r := http.NewServeMux()
    srv := &http.Server{
        Addr:    ":0",
        Handler: r,
    }

    go func() {
        if err := srv.ListenAndServe(); err != nil {
            fmt.Println("An error occured.")
        }
    }()
    // Block until a signal is received.
    <-c
    srv.Close()
    fmt.Println("rr")
    <-time.After(time.Second)
}
```

Comment: Your code renders an error: `panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference`